# How to create a date time vector and running MM:SS count vector within a date time range in R

Tags: r, datetime, count

I have a start datetime and an end datetime, and I would like to create a datetime vector that runs within this range at 1-second intervals. I would also like to create a second column in MM:SS format that counts up in time from 00:00 onwards.

Example:

```
df = structure(list(Starttime = "07/04/17 13:04:11", Endtime = "07/04/17 13:12:34"), .Names = c("Starttime", 
"Endtime"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -1L))
```

Desired output:

```
Datetime    Second_count
07/04/17 13:04:11   00:00
07/04/17 13:04:12   00:01
07/04/17 13:04:13   00:02
07/04/17 13:04:14   00:03
07/04/17 13:04:15   00:04
07/04/17 13:04:16   00:05
```

And so on……….

Any help with this task would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my `lubridate` solution:

```
library(lubridate)

int <- interval(start = dmy_hms(df$Starttime), 
                end = dmy_hms(df$Endtime))

seq <- seq(dmy_hms(df$Starttime), dmy_hms(df$Endtime), "sec")

sec <- seconds_to_period(seq_along(seq) - 1)

sec <- sprintf('%02d:%02d', minute(sec), second(sec))

final <- data.frame(
  Datetime = seq, 
  Second_count = sec
)
```

Comment: Amazing! Thanks so much! :)